# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement in radio button

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

How can I put a space and text to it

```
if (ViewBag.Institution == "Male")
{
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="male" checked="checked"  />&nbsp; Male &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="male" />&nbsp; Female &nbsp;
}
```

Comment: Wrap the text in a span element and give it some padding

Comment: Agree with @StephenMuecke you should be using HTML/CSS to solve your layout issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the non breaking spaces, outside of an angle tag, razor interprets them as code.

Try this:

```
if (ViewBag.Institution == "Male")
{
    <text>
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="male" checked="checked"  />&nbsp; Male &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="female" />&nbsp; Female &nbsp;
    </text>
}
```

Razor will now treat the full string as text.  Fixed what looks like a typo in your code too, unless you want all of the radios to have the value male

Comment: The `name` attributes need to be the same otherwise it wont work as a radio button group - its just that the code is nonsense and wont do anything. The radio buttons need `value` attributes so it should be something like `name="gender" value="male"` and `name="gender" value="female"` :)